# WINDBG: Display dump file capture flags

Tags: windbg, minidump

This is a very quick question. I searched and can't seem to find the windbg command that would show what options exist in a minidump file.

Additionally, I would like to get back the equivalent argument to the `.dump` command that would generate the same type of minidump, for example `.dump /ma`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.dumpdebug will give you the flags that the mini-dump was created with. For example:

```
0:000> .dumpdebug
----- User Mini Dump Analysis

MINIDUMP_HEADER:
Version         A793 (6C02)
NumberOfStreams 11
Flags           1806
                0002 MiniDumpWithFullMemory
                0004 MiniDumpWithHandleData
                0800 MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo
                1000 MiniDumpWithThreadInfo
```

It will also spew lots of other information, so just be patient and then scroll back to the top :)

-scott

Comment: It works but oddly enough it's not in the help file packaged with windbg 6.12.0002.633

Comment: It's an undocumented command, though it's been there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

When you first open a dump usually the 4th line of text will be something like this:

**User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available**

or

**User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available**

This will obviously change depending upon what the options were.

Comment: Huh. Never paid attention to this text before. Doesn't map back exactly but its a start.