# How can I know the type of a Windows dump file?

Tags: windows, dump, postmortem-debugging

I have a dump file and I would like to know its "type", for example according
[Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) *user mode dump* has three basic `DumpType`: `0: Custom dump`, `1: Mini dump`, `2: Full dump`.

According to [Varieties of Kernel-Mode Dump Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/varieties-of-kernel-mode-dump-files) *kernel mode dump* has five types: 
Complete Memory Dump, Kernel Memory Dump, Small Memory Dump, Automatic Memory Dump, 
Active Memory Dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the DMP file in [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools). The type will be displayed once loaded, for example:

```
Loading Dump File [C:\etc\notepad.DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available
```

While the DMP is loaded, the type can be retrieved with the `||` command:

```
0:000> ||
.  0 Full memory user mini dump: C:\etc\notepad.DMP
```

Comment: Ok, I get slightly different descriptions too :`Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available` and `.  0 64-bit Kernel triage dump`

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson Indeed, there are several types of DMPs even beyond those listed (including "*custom*" dumps). See for example the `-m` options of [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump).

Comment: You can see how to get the actual flags in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556665/1218218